# Populate a List<T> and DataGridView with contents of an SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview, sqldatareader

I am trying to write a function that can take three parameters: an SqlDataReader, a DataGridView and a List.

I want to take the contents of the SqlDataReader and create a list of Objects, then bind this to the DataGridView.

With a few pointers from another Stack Overflow user I came up with the following:

```
public void FillArrayList<T>(DataGridView grid, SqlDataReader reader, List<T> list)
{
    //Fill the list with the contents of the reader
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Object obj = new Object();
        Type type = typeof(T);

        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(); // Get the fields of the assembly
        int i = 0;

        foreach(var field in fields)
        {
            field.SetValue(obj, reader[i]); // set the fields of T to the reader's value
            i++;
        }

        list.Add((T)obj);
    }

    grid.DataSource = list;
}
```

When I run the code, I get an error when casting the object to type T:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type
>   'TestHarness.Organisation'.

I was under the impression that an Object could store anything. Can anyone advise me on why this cast cannot be performed?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: check this might help you. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174537/how-to-pass-a-list-of-unknown-objects-of-type-custom-class-containing-some-prope][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174537/how-to-pass-a-list-of-unknown-objects-of-type-custom-class-containing-some-prope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from the link posted by MMK, in the comment below my question, I have devised a solution:

```
public void FillList<T>(DataGridView grid, string SQLCommand, List<T> list) where T : class, new()
    {
        //Load the data into the SqlDataReader
        SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
        dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;
        dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        dataCommand.CommandText = SQLCommand;

        SqlDataReader dataReader = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();

        //Fill the list with the contents of the reader
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var obj = new T();

            //Get the property information
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            int i = 0;

            foreach(var property in properties)
            {
                property.SetValue((T)obj, dataReader[i], null); // set the fields of T to the reader's value
                i++;
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        dataReader.Close();

        //Bind the list to the DataGridView
        grid.DataSource = list;
    }
```

Seems to do exactly what I need. It's possible I may come across some obvious error as I use this in more and more situations, but, this is life.

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can cast nearly anything to Object, but you can't cast Object to anything.  Take a look at the [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) class on MSDN.  Notice how there's almost nothing there.  The cast doesn't make sense because it's functionally the same as doing calling a new TestHarness.Organization.

If you know exactly what you're looking for in the DataReader to go into TestHarness.Organization or whatever it is, you might try a [user-defined conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  This would allow you to either implicitly or explicitly call some code to do the type change for you without any extra code on the spot.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I did originally have a method that took an OrganisationList and an OrganisationGrid. Easy to implement, but I needed a very similar method to fill a JobGrid with the contents of a JobList. I saw that the code could be improved by writing a method that could handle a list of _anything_. Is it possible to add an unknown Object to a generic List<T>?

Comment: Not as such, no.  You can generically declare a List<T> but for compilation purposes everything will have to be a T as you add it in, which isn't very useful because you can't access anything about T.  I think what you're actually looking for is a good implementation of [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx).  If you were to make OrgGrid and JobGrid both implement the interface IWorkGrid or whatever you call it, you can then make a List<IWorkGrid> and do what you want with that.